# Concurrent Modification exception for this code block, Help Please?

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist

missedMSRB is a List with 2187 elements in it and when trying to run the below snippet

```
List<List<String>> subList = getSubList(missedMSRB, 1000);

    for (List<String> subMSRB : subList) {

        StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer(NamedQueries.msSQL); 
        sql.append("(");

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < subMSRB.size(); i1++) {  //Line 463 Throws Exception

            if (i1 < subMSRB.size() - 1) {
                sql.append("?,");
            } else {
                sql.append("? )");

            }

        } ....
```

Code fails with the follwoing exception any suggestions why i am getting concurrent modification and how to get rid of the same

```
13 Jan 2015 10:42:58,974 [main] ERROR  RunAnalytics:  General Error: null
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1169)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:998)
    at com.abc.Analytics.RunAnalytics.getCountCheck(RunAnalytics.java:463)
    at com.abc.Analytics.RunAnalytics.analyticsExecute(RunAnalytics.java:342)
    at com.abc.Analytics.RunAnalytics.main(RunAnalytics.java:84)
```

Remaining code below

```
PreparedStatement psMSQL2 = msSQL.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

    psMSQL2.setString(1, runDate);
    psMSQL2.setString(2, runDate2);

    int i = 3;
    for (String s : subMSRB) {
        psMSQL2.setString(i, s.trim());
        i++;
    }

    ResultSet msSQL = psMSQL2.executeQuery();
    logger.debug("SQL executed");

    while (msSQL.next()) {
        missedMSRB.remove(msSQL.getString(1));
    }
```

getSubList impl// *Corrected*

```
public static List<List<String>> getSubList(List<String> inputList, int subListSize) {

        int listSize = inputList.size();
        int noOfLoops = listSize / subListSize;
        int remainingListSize = listSize % subListSize;

        List<List<String>> subList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfLoops; i++) {
            int fromIndex = i * subListSize;
            int toIndex = (fromIndex) + subListSize;
            subList.add(new ArrayList<String>(inputList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));

            if ((remainingListSize != 0)
                    && (toIndex == (listSize - remainingListSize))) {
                subList.add(new ArrayList<String>(inputList.subList(toIndex, listSize)));

            }
        }

        return subList;

    }
```

Comment: any other thread modifying the lists ?

Comment: is something else modifying  `subMSRB`?  (as per your sample code doesn't show that)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something there isn't enough info here to explain the problem. You get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if you change a `List` while iterating over it. Can you post more code?

Comment: addded code as requested

Comment: @njzk2  No i am running this in a simple main program on my PC.

Comment: @all i access the subMSRB elements to form the params of the sql, i never edit the subMSRB list explicitly, that is the issue i am facing

Comment: Just an aside, joining strings is a solved problem.  In Java 8, `String params = Collections.nCopies(subMSRB.size(), "?").stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))`.  Prior to Java 8, use Guava: `String params = Joiner.on(",").join(Collections.nCopies(subMSRB.size(), "?"))`

Comment: I notice the Exception is thrown from ArrayList$SubList - i.e. an inner class within ArrayList.  I wonder how your getSubList() method works?  That might help us work out what's going on - at the moment the snippets you post run fine in a simple main program here.

Comment: @MarkPeters i am still on Java 6u29 so not a viable option for me yet.

Comment: @JRichardSnape added the requested impl.

Comment: this `missedMSRB.remove` changes the `missedMSRB` list, which is used by `subMSRB` because `inputList.subList` returns a view on the same list, and not a different list.

Comment: @njzk2 is right - that is what's doing it.  Beat me by a couple of seconds - recommend putting that into an answer (I'll +1 it)

Comment: ok so to resslve this i make a copy of missedMSRB and remove from the same rather then using it.

Comment: @SHinny: That's why included instructions for doing it with Guava, which is compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getSubList` you create several lists using `inputList.subList`. This method from `List` implemented in `ArrayList` does not create a new List. Instead, it returns a view of `inputList`, and is therefore backed by `inputList`.

Any modification to `inputList` has an impact on the sublist.  You have passed `missedMSRB` in as `inputList`, so any modification to `missedMSRB` will impact on `subList`

Therefore, when you call `missedMSRB.remove` within the outer `for` loop, you create a `ConcurrentModification` to all the lists in `subList`.  When you then check the size of one of this lists in `subList` it throws the `ConcurrentModificationException`

To solve this, you can for example create a new list instead of using directly the result of `subList`:

```
subList.add(new ArrayList<String>(inputList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));
```